# Zend Studio 9 messes up indentation

Tags: zend-studio

I'm moving my project from Zend Studio 5 to 9.

Zend 9 ruins my indentation.  Previously my code was formatted to have a tab be two spaces.  Now Zend is using four spaces and some lines are indented further than before.

```
Before:
  $a=1;
  $b=1;
  $c=1;
  for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
  {
    echo "test";
  }

Now
  $a=1;
    $b=1;
    $c=1;
    for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
    {
        echo "test";
    }
```

I've tried setting the tab policy to "spaces" and the indentation size to "2".  But that doesn't work.

Comment: When I change the editor indentation settings, it does not seem to have any impact on my project files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by setting Displayed tab width to "2".

This is on the page: General > Editors > Text Editors

Comment: This doesn't work for me, using Zend Studio 9 with Linux. It seems that blank spaces at the beginning of the line are not displayed correctly, e.g. if I indent a line to 32 spaces, it will not align with colum 32 in the line above (that starts with non-space-characters earlier). This is very annoying and makes code hard to read - indenting lines with more spaces (even then sometimes the difference is just a few pixels, so you can't align all lines using this method) will make the code messed up in other editors.